# Synapse Analytics RenameDataFactoryResourceError error when trying to publish a rename pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I'm trying to publish a reanaming pipeline and I'm getting this error and don't know how to deal with

```
Error code: OK
Inner error code: RenameDataFactoryResourceError
Message: {"code":"InternalError","message":"Internal error has occurred.","target":null,"details":null,"error":null}
```

I've already tried to rename the pipeline again but the error persists when I try to publish the pipeline.

Comment: I'm not going to lie - resolving Publish errors is an absolute train wreck. And 99% of the time they have to do with renaming resources. The first thing I would try is to change the pipeline back to the original name and republish. Then create a new branch that only renames the pipeline, merge it, and try to publish again. If that does not work, put in a support ticket.

Comment: I'm going to try this new branch approach. The publish had other changes besides the renaming, after changing back to the original name the publish worked. But I still can't publish the rename change. After the branch approach I will give you some feedback

Comment: Update: tried to change the name back to the old name, create a new branch and do the merge. Unfortunately it didn't worked. I'm going to open a support ticket.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I tried many ways, no luck. Except for one. I disconnected Github in Synapse, then reconnected. Working now.

Comment: Now you can rename items and publish?

Comment: Thanks for the question. Because I've learned more about this issue after I posted my response. When I disconnected Synapse from Github and reconnected, it redownloaded the original filename of the component I renamed, while still retaining the one I renamed it from. Then I was able to publish. So no, renaming is still a problem and is clearly a bug in the Git and Synapse integration. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue myself. I fixed it by reverting the commit(s) that renamed the files. For the record, I *hate* this approach, but Synapse seems to have problems renaming things.

Comment: After that you could rename the item and publish the pipeline?

Comment: I did not try to re (re?) name the pipeline, but I have done it in the past and it worked. I think it may have to do with assets that reference other assets, so in this case I renamed both Pipeline A and Pipeline B: Pipeline A executed Pipeline B, so there was an internal reference. The reference was properly updated, but my guess is the Live version didn't know how to handle the nested rename.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here. I used the Pending Changes log to revert the names back on Main branch and republished. That fixed it.

Anything highlighted in yellow, I renamed back with the old name. [image]

Comment: Reverting the name worked to publish the other changes but I still can't change the names of any pipeline and publish

Comment: @GabrielPadilha If you're still having an issue, grant me temp access and I can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disconnecting the GIT mode, you can also overwrite live mode from within Synapse. Afterwards, this issue was fixed for me. This saves the hassle from disconnecting and reconnecting.

[image]